# MySQL: error when query returns no results?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT number
            FROM table1
            INNER JOIN table2
            WHERE name = 'stack_overflow' AND table1.id = table2.id
            AND user_id = 5
```

This returns a number. It does the right thing, but when inside name I pass a name that does not exist in db, PHP gives me an error. This is how I am executing it:

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $x = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

I always get the correct $x value when the name exists in the table, however when it doesn't, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name_that_is_not_in_table'

No idea....

Comment: Show the actual query that causes this error.

Comment: What is the `name_that_is_not_in_table` ? Does it include any special characters which might break the query?

Comment: no... it is a normal string that just does not exist, i execute the query and it just returns no values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass name in this way:

```
SELECT number
            FROM table1
            INNER JOIN table2
            WHERE name = ? AND table1.id = table2.id
            AND user_id = 5

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($name));
$x = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Not exactly what I did, but helped me get to the solution. Binding the value did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to check how many rows are returned first... if none, notify the user.  If it DOES have a returned row count, then get the name column as you are expecting.

Additionally, you should clarify the alias.column in your queries as anyone new doesn't have to guess which table a given column comes from...  Such as your user_id and name columns.  (and "name" might be a reserved word and cause the choke... so you might want to wrap it in tick marks

```
`name`
```